# Npgsql Connection Forcibly Closed C#

Tags: c#, npgsql

I don't know why but whenever I try to connect to my database this happens

`SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.`

I'm using C# and Npgsql with my connection.json is like this

```
{
  "server": "localhost",
  "port": "5432",
  "database": "Postgres2",
  "userID": "postgres",
  "password": "admin"
}
```

and my code looks like this

```
string serverConfigLocation = "Data/conn.json";
async void Start()
{
    var cS = new ConnectionString();
    if(File.Exists(serverConfigLocation))
    {
        using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(serverConfigLocation))
        {
            var json = r.ReadToEnd();
            cS = ConnectionString.FromJson(json);
        }
    }
    
    System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = 
    System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls | 
    System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
    var connectionString = "Host=" + cS.server + ";Username=" + cS.userID + ";Password=" 
    + cS.password + ";Database=" + cS.database;

    await using var conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionString);
    await conn.OpenAsync();
}
```

Comment: TLS and TLS1 are obsolete and should not be used.  Use TLS2 or TLS3.  You need to use Net 4.7.2 or later to be sure code will run.  Also your URL has to be HTTPS (not HTTP) to use TLS.

Comment: @jdweng Sorry for the late reply, I think the problem was my PgAdmin program itself. After I tried reinstall it worked.

Comment: Maybe you had an old version installed.  I do not think installing the same version would of fixed a TLS issue.

Comment: @jdweng yep, I think so too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done, I reinstalled my PgAdmin and PostgreSql and it worked like a charm. Don't know how that happen though.